# C# Manually Map Non JSON File into JSON

Tags: c#, json, mapping, byte, data-conversion

I'm currently parsing an extensionless save file from a game. Most of the property names are encoded with a nonstandard encoding, so I'm comparing multiple save files and seeing where the bytes are changing and noting the mapping that way.
For example, I found that the bytes "80-3F" map as the "Position" for an item, where the following 12 bytes make up the X,Y,Z values, with 4 bytes each.

Once I get all the mappings noted, I'd like to be able to convert the file into JSON, in a format similar to:

```
{
    "headerBytes": "~",
    "items": [
        {
            "headerBytes": "~",
            "position": {
                "x": "00-00-00-00",
                "y": "00-00-00-00",
                "z": "00-00-00-00"
            },
            "bytesBetweenPositionAndRotation": "~",
            "rotation": {
                "x": "~",
                "y": "~",
                "z": "~"
            },
            "footerBytes": "~"
        }
    ],
    "footerBytes": "~"
}
```

(Where the different byte properties would just be the string of bytes that don't change between files, such as properties I don't care about and want to leave alone)
And then use that JSON to convert to DTO objects to make changes, convert back to JSON and then back to the original file format to use in game.

Does C# have anyway to do this easily? (Searching online just returns results for standard JSON to DTO conversions) Or would I have to manually read through the original file and use StringBuilder to build the JSON? If that's the case, would it just be better to read the original file and build the DTO objects right there without building a JSON string?

Comment: I think you probably want to build up a proper object model of different values, then serialize *that* into JSON using a standard JSON serializer.

Comment: If the data is stored in some custom format you will need to write a custom parser. Personally I would go with direct parsing to classes instead of some interim JSON.